# Changing the Reference in the formula For Each Cell in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, indexing, match

I have a subroutine to apply an Index/Match to a range of 7 cells, looking up against a named range with a different Index value applied to the formula in each cell.

I have a version of it that works, but I'm trying to trim my code down so I don't have a long and unwieldy sub. I'm sure there's a way to get it to work in a For Each Cell loop, but for the life of me I can't figure out how. I could probably figure it out using a vlookup, but I believe an Index/Match is a better solution when looking up against large ranges of data (my named table is over 10k rowslong)

Here's what I have that actually works but is a bit long:

```
    Range("C38:F38").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[NAME],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
Range("C39:F39").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_1],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
Range("C40:F40").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_2],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
Range("C41:F41").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_3],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
Range("C42:F42").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.TOWN],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
Range("C43:F43").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.COUNTY],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
Range("C44:F44").Select
    Selection.MergeCells = True
    Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA[infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.POST_CODE],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
```

And here I've figured out how to apply the loop to deal with the merging part, but I'm stumped on how to do the Index/Match changing just the column headers on the Index in each instance:

```
For Each Cell In Range("C38:C44").Cells
    Cell.Resize(, 4).Select
    Selection.Merge
    'Something in here with the Index/Match Formula changing the Column Header on each turn through the loop
Next Cell
```

Any thoughts or advice very gratefully appreciated.

Comment: PS - I'm aware the column header names are really long, but they pull out of Access that way. I'll look into changing those in the Access Query at a later date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up an array for the column names and concatenate them in the loop. You just need to keep track of the column.

```
Dim columnNames(6) As String
Dim i as Integer
i=0


columnNames(0) = "NAME"
'Rest of columns.
columnNames(6) = "infodyn_DELIVERY_ADDRESS.POST_CODE"

'Inside loop
 Selection.Formula = ("=IFERROR(INDEX(MAIN_DATA["&  columnNames(i) &"],MATCH($D$10,MAIN_DATA[PURCHASE_ORDER_ID],FALSE),0),"""")")
i = i +1
```

Comment: Stellar! That cracked the problem and introduced me to a lovely useful piece of coding.